# SQL Join sum data together by field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query that gets the total orders, total price of all the orders combined and group them by a users name.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `customers`.`name`          AS 'name',
    count(`orders`.`id`)        AS 'total orders',
    sum(`orderDetails`.`price`) AS 'total price'

FROM `customers`

INNER JOIN `orders`
ON 
    `orders`.`customer_id`      = `customers`.`id`

INNER JOIN `orderDetails`
ON
    `orderDetails`.`order_id`   = `orders`.`id`

WHERE 
    `customers`.`company_id`    = 1

GROUP BY
    `orders`.`id`,    -- Removing this will have the users grouped correctly, 
                      -- but display an invalid count.
    `customers`.`id`
```

Currently I'm getting a result like such:

```
'John', '2', '2.0000'
'Bill', '3', '3.0000'
'Bill', '1', '1.0000'
'John', '2', '2.0000'
'John', '3', '3.0000'
```

When in reality:

```
John has 3 orders with a total price of 7.00
Bill has 2 orders with a total price of 4.00
```

Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: Only do `GROUP BY customers.name`

Comment: @M.Ali That results in the total orders ending up having the same value as total price

Comment: Do you not have a column called `Quantity` in your `OrderDetails` table? Summing just price seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is grouping at different levels. However, in this case you can fix it by using `count(distinct`

```
select
    `customers`.`name` as 'name',
    count(distinct `orders`.`id`) as 'total orders',
    sum(`orderDetails`.`price`) as 'total price'
from
    `customers`
        inner join
    `orders`
        on `orders`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id`
        inner join
    `orderDetails`
        on `orderDetails`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
where
    `customers`.`company_id` = 1
group by
   `customers`.`id`,
   `customers`.`name`
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll only need one group by statement:

```
GROUP BY
`customers`.`name`
```

Comment: That results in the total amount of orders being incorrect (having the same value as the total price)

Comment: It shouldn't can you provide the data you're using?